# How can I create ionic 2 tabs custom title

Tags: ionic2

I have this in my ion-content

```
<ion-content >    
  <super-tabs>
    <super-tab [root]="page1" title="First page" icon="home"></super-tab>
    <super-tab [root]="page2" title="Second page" icon="pin"></super-tab>
    <super-tab [root]="page3" title="Third page" icon="heart"></super-tab>
  </super-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

The result will be -> http://prntscr.com/h10myc

I want my tabs result as expected -> http://prntscr.com/h10sk1

Is that possible? Can I create a custom title in ionic tabs?

So that, I can add numbers above the title. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way of doing that without using a custom-built tab-interface. However, an alternative way to do this would be to implement a `tabBadge` property with the number that you desire. For example,

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabBadge="25" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Pizza" tabBadge="18" tabIcon="cafe"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabBadge="49" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Your best bet is to make a custom navigation component by using the navcontroller commands and buttons or someting else

Comment: Thanks for your help, I already achieved the design using sass and your recommendation about `tabBadge`

Comment: Good stuff. Feel free to post your answer on here so other people can know for the duture